# How to get HREF from h2 tag? Python/Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

URL: https://www.nielsen.com/us/en/insights/related-tag/covid-19/

I have the following HTML elements:

[image]

I want to extract href from this class and the text of title.

I used `driver.find_element_by_class_name('h2.entry-title h1>a').get_attribute('href)` but returned none.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did in the first place is wrong. You perhaps wanted to use `driver.find_element_by_css_selector()` instead of `driver.find_element_by_class_name()`. However, the better way of doing the same would be to go for requests library as the content you look for are available in the page source. Try running the following script to get them all traversing multiple pages.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.nielsen.com/us/en/insights/related-tag/covid-19/'

while True:
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    for item in soup.select("article"):
        article_link = item.select_one("h2.entry-title > a[href]")['href']
        article_title = item.select_one("h2.entry-title > a[href]").get_text(strip=True)
        print(article_link,article_title)

    try:
        link = soup.select_one("a[class^='next']")['href']
    except TypeError:
        break
```

If it is still selenium you wanna stick with, this is how you can do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    driver.get("https://www.nielsen.com/us/en/insights/related-tag/covid-19/")

    while True:
        for elem in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"article"))):
            article_link = WebDriverWait(elem,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h2.entry-title > a[href]"))).get_attribute("href")
            article_title = WebDriverWait(elem,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h2.entry-title > a[href]"))).text
            print(article_link,article_title)

        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class^='next']"))).click()
            WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.staleness_of(elem))
        except:
            break
```

Comment: Thank you @SIM! The block of code is really helpful. I should keep learning the web scraping!

Comment: Hi @SIM, I have another question posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235160/python-selenium-how-to-loop-through-hrefs-in-li Can you please help me with the question as well? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @SIM, from the first block of code - what is try except break doing? Does it go over the next page? Thanks!

Comment: Yep, it keeps clicking on the next page link. When there is none, it will break the loop.