# Python/Selenium - how to loop through hrefs in <li>?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Web URL: https://www.ipsos.com/en-us/knowledge/society/covid19-research-in-uncertain-times

I want to parse the HTML as below:

[image]

I want to get all hrefs within the < li > elements and the highlighted text. I tried the code

```
elementList = driver.find_element_by_class_name('block-wysiwyg').find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for i in range(len(elementList)):
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('blcokwysiwyg').find_elements_by_tag_name("li").get_attribute("href")
```

But the block returned none.

Can anyone please help me with the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it will fetch you the required content.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.ipsos.com/en-us/knowledge/society/covid19-research-in-uncertain-times'

r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
for item in soup.select(".block-wysiwyg li"):
    item_text = item.get_text(strip=True)
    item_link = item.select_one("a[href]").get("href")
    print(item_text,item_link)
```

Comment: Hi @SIM, I don't know why the bs4 does not work on my end and the block returns SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.ipsos.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:

Comment: I ran and found success just now. If you still encounter the same error, try defining a headers like `requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})`.

Comment: I figured it out the bs4: requests.get(link, verify=False) it will work

Comment: Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try is this way:

```
coronas = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='block-wysiwyg']/ul/li")
hr = coronas.find_element_by_xpath('./a')
print(coronas.text)
print(hr.get_attribute('href'))
```

Output:

```
The coronavirus is touching the lives of all Americans, but race, age, and income play a big role in the exact ways the virus — and the stalled economy — are affecting people. Here's what that means.
https://www.ipsos.com/en-us/america-under-coronavirus
```

Comment: The block returns error NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element...I suspect something wrong with the path?

Comment: @Bangbangbang No, the xpath works (just tried it again). Can't explain why it doesn't work on your side.